# Is there a better way to get a cookie value in ActionFilterAttribute?

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, asp.net-web-api, actionfilterattribute

I have an ActionFilterAttribute that needs to get a cookie value from the request. Here's the relevant code:

```
List<CookieState> cookies = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies("NameOfTheCookieIWant").FirstOrDefault().Cookies.ToList();

if (cookies == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("cookie");
}

string value = "";
cookies.ForEach(cookie => {
    if (cookie.Name == "NameOfTheCookieIWant") {
        value = cookie.Value;
    }
});
```

So I have to go into the headers and get the cookie header that contains the name of the cookie I want. But this gives me a collection of CookieHeaderValues, so I have to take the first of these, which itself contains a Cookies property which is a collection of CookieStates. I turn this collection into a list and run a forEach on it until I find the CookieState whose name matches the name of the cookie I want, then save off the value of that CookieState.

It seems crazy to me that I need to go through so much just to get a cookie value. Surely there's a better, more direct way to get one particular cookie, whose name I know, and its value?

Comment: Is your question about MVC or WebApi project? Please add relevant tag. It seems to be about WebApi though.

Comment: I knew I forgot one. Added asp.net-web-api tag, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cookie = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies("NameOfTheCookieIWant").FirstOrDefault();

if (cookie != null)
{
    string val = cookie["NameOfTheCookieIWant"].Value;
}
```

Comment: Here is a [link](https://github.com/datafile4/book-store/blob/beta/BookStore/BookStore/Controllers/Attributes.cs) to a sample WebApi project that my friends and I are currently working on which is for only learning  purposes. It is on development phase for now but I think you'll find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

```
var cookie = actionContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["NameOfTheCookieIWant"];
var value = cookie == null ? "" : cookie.Value
```

Comment: I get "'HttpActionExecutedContext' does not contain a definition for 'RequestContext'" when I try to do this; perhaps this is an MVC solution that doesn't work in WebAPI?

Comment: This answer seems to be for MVC project, while question is about WebApi. But it is not your fault, the author added neither of tags.

Comment: null checking can be simplified as`var value = cookie?.Value ?? "";`

Answer (score 0):

I would say write a wrapper class or a utility function for getting the cookie values especially if you have to do this over and over.